# How to enqueue and then call a second JQuery version in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

first post here, I would really appreciate some help with a JQuery problem I'm having. I have a Wordpress site with VERY specific carousel / slider requirements that can be met using Flexslider2, which unfortunately requires JQuery 1.7. I know I need to make use of noconflict here and have looked at the documentation but am a total dunce wherever Javascript is concerned and can't figure out how to use it in my specific case. Currently I am enqueuing the script in the footer, so it is causing the other stuff that relies on a more recent version of JQuery not to work. I'm just not sure exactly how and where to call JQuery 1.7, and then how to modify the script under the gallery itself to make sure it, and only it, uses the 1.7 version. Thank you so much!

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery17', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js', array(), null );
```

The code on the page under the list of images then looks like this (as I have a slider and a carousel that are linked)

```
    $(window).load(function() {
$('#carousel').flexslider({
animation: "slide",
controlNav: false,
animationLoop: false,
slideshow: false,
itemWidth: 100,
itemMargin: 5,
asNavFor: '#slider'
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
animation: "slide",
controlNav: false,
animationLoop: false,
slideshow: false,
sync: "#carousel"
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, and likely the only valid way is to manually output the needed script tag & enable no conflict mode directly in your html.

You could do it via the wp_footer hook with a very high priority to not interfere with other plugins.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_custom_scripts', 500 );
function my_custom_scripts() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.noConflict();
    </script><?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can see 1.7 now being called in the footer, and it is not interfering with the other JQuery dependent stuff, but my slider / carousel is also not working. Do I need to modify the code for that to tell it which version of JQuery to use?

Comment: Hmm, likely because your sliders JS is not loading after this. The tricky part is you can't modify the sliders JS to use the second copy of jQuery.

Comment: That is to say you may have to try it without noConflict and force the sliders JS to load after your new copy of jQuery.

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel for your help. I think a more modern slider is the only satisfactory solution. I have found a really good one and hopefully will be able to convince the client that it will do a better job!

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('init', 'my_register_styles');

function my_register_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'style1', get_template_directpry_uri() . '/style1.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'style2', get_template_directpry_uri() . '/style2.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'style3', get_template_directpry_uri() . '/style3.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_styles' );

function my_enqueue_styles() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style3' );
    } elseif ( is_page_template( 'special.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style1' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style2' );
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style1' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on post id you can enque script, so you can avoid  conflict.

Comment: Thank you! There is only one template that I need to use the old version on, but unfortunately, I need the recent version on every page, so I think there would still be a conflict?